# Get height of cell in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, height, subclass

I have a table view in which the cells are subclassed. In the subclass I call a subclass of UIView.
I have implemented `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and would like to retrieve this height in my subclass to set the height of the instance of my subclassed UIView.

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried using `self.bounds.size.height` and `self.contentView.frame.size.height` but none of these seem to give the correct height.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        textCellView = [[TextCellView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:textCellView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time it is created the subview has not be positioned, and so you cannot rely on the frame.  Instead, try passing the value into your init method on the custom table cell.  Nothing says you have to use the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method.  Here's an example:

```
- (id) initWithHeight: (CGFloat) cellHeight {
  if ((self = [super initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                   reuseIdentifier: @"MyCustomTableViewCell"])) {
    // perform all layout that needs to happen
    // use cellHeight in all the layout calculations 
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I thought the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` method was default and mandatory. Can you by any chance tell me why my heights are messing up if I do not create the cells in the table view everytime they are scrolled by? That means that I cannot use `if(cell == nil){ // Create cell }`. I believe it will be too resource heavy to create the cell every time the cell is scrolled by. I think Apple uses `if(cell == nil)` in their examples.

Comment: Are your cells supposed to be of different heights?  If so, when you pick your cell out and it's not nil you'll have to set the height again manually, and have it recalculate the layout.  If this is the case you may want to use a height setter instead of setting it on init.  Feel free to post code.

Comment: I don't know the height of my cells. I calculate it by the size of the labels, spacing and so on. I figured it might be best to ask a new question for this issue so I made one regarding reuse of cells with variable height. I got it working by making the cell identifier variable but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it. I have posted some code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962411/multiple-reuse-identifiers-in-a-uitableview Here I don't use a height setter but I set the height on init (as in your example) but I will reuse cells with the same height.

Comment: I have implemented this and am initializing the cell by:
`cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithHeight:[self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];`
It works like a charm with dynamic height!

Comment: A bit too fast there. Had to use dynamic cellIdentifiers as well `NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%f", [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];`